# Draw route on map in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift3, routes, swift4, mapkit

I want draw route between two coordinates in swift4.
and I am using this code,

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!


var myRoute : MKRoute!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let point1 = MKPointAnnotation()
    let point2 = MKPointAnnotation()

    point1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.0305, 121.5360)
    point1.title = "Taipei"
    point1.subtitle = "Taiwan"
    myMap.addAnnotation(point1)

    point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.9511, 121.2358)
    point2.title = "Chungli"
    point2.subtitle = "Taiwan"
    myMap.addAnnotation(point2)
    myMap.centerCoordinate = point2.coordinate
    myMap.delegate = self

    //Span of the map

    myMap.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(point2.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.7,0.7)), animated: true)

    let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

    let markTaipei = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point1.coordinate.latitude, point1.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)

    let markChungli = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point2.coordinate.latitude, point2.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)

    directionsRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: markChungli)
    directionsRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: markTaipei)

    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)

    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {

        response, error in

        if error == nil {

            self.myRoute = response!.routes[0] as MKRoute

            self.myMap.add(self.myRoute.polyline)

        }
    })
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) ->MKOverlayRenderer {

    let myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: myRoute.polyline)

    myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red

    myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3

    return myLineRenderer
}
}
```

and this code give me right answer
[image]

But when I change coordinates then it not show route.
new coordinates are
point1 = 26.9124, 75.7873
point2 = 26.9124, 76.7873

Comment: Right now, if `calculate` fails to get a route, you're not looking at what the error object is. If you're wondering why you're not getting a route, I'd suggest examining what that `error` is.

Comment: expression produced error: error: /var/folders/g5/747t2c710z36d6rc4w22ds_m0000gn/T/./lldb/1003/expr12.swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'Builtin'
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Builtin.RawPointer>(bitPattern: 0x121bba200)!.pointee)

Comment: Unrelated, but your `rendererFor` is referencing `myRoute.polyline`. You shouldn't be doing that. It just opens you up to problems. You should be taking the `overlay` that was passed to this delegate message and create your renderer from that. E.g. `let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)`.

Comment: Those new coordinates are in India, and it just looks like directions are not available there. I get an error that says "Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=4 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available, MKErrorGEOError=-8, MKErrorGEOErrorUserInfo={
}, MKErrorGEOTransitIncidentKey=<_GEOTransitRoutingIncidentMessage: 0x60800023df20>, MKDirectionsErrorCode=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Directions are not available between these locations.}"

Comment: FYI, I tried in the Apple Maps app, and the directions button just doesn't appear in this area...

Comment: there are no another option for draw route in India.

Comment: Looks like Apple Maps doesn't yet support India. (https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-we-see-route-directions-on-Apples-Maps-app-in-India) I guess if this is a critical part of your app, you may have to consider Google Maps.

Comment: yes then I use google map API. Thanx bro.. :)

Comment: hello, your using :   self.myRoute = response!.routes[0] as MKRoute what is that meaning i get error when i try with this coede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Apple Maps doesn't yet support India. ([quora.com/…](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-we-see-route-directions-on-Apples-Maps-app-in-India)) I guess if this is a critical part of your app, you may have to consider Google Maps

Those new coordinates are in India, and it just looks like directions are not available there. I get an error that says "Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=4 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available, MKErrorGEOError=-8, MKErrorGEOErrorUserInfo={ }, MKErrorGEOTransitIncidentKey=<_GEOTransitRoutingIncidentMessage: 0x60800023df20>, MKDirectionsErrorCode=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Directions are not available between these locations.}"

Thanx Rob for this answar.